# Can we not determine the minimum and maximum value of a function by just obtaining the value of the function at the critical points?

Tags: calculus, optimization

Can we do the above or is it neccessary to find the sign of the second derivative. I find no problem with any of the above but the answer of the following question left me confused.

"The real number x when added to its inverse gives the minimum value of the sum when x equals?"
The given answer is 1.
The critical points are 1 and -1.
The value of the function at 1 is 2 and that at -1 is -2.
So the sum is minimum at -1 but if we check the sign of second derivative, the answer is 1. 
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement only works when the function is continuous in a closed interval. Otherwise you have to use the first derivative or second derivative test.

Here is a picture of your function:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The function is discontinuous (at $x=0$).  The local minimum at $x=1$ is greater than the local maximum at $x=-1$.  You may want to graph the function.

Answer (score 0):

$$ y = x + 1/x$$
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=1-\frac{1}{x^2}$$
has extrema at $$ x = \pm 1 $$

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=+\frac{2}{x^3}$$

At $ x = +1, $ it is a local minimum.

At $ x = -1, $ it is a local *maximum*, please note carefully.

Where is the confusion? A drawing also confirms all the above.

The second derivative test helps verify what you assume you know by intuition.